# Request timeout issue with the post rest API request

Tags: time, request, jersey

My application environment is Tomcat 7.0, JDK 1.7. I am using Jersey for the REST API.  One of our post type REST API request takes the processing more than 3 minutes, and it is just approx time, it can be more than 3 minutes. Then we send the response back to the client when our request processing is completed. but here request processing take 3 minutes so I got the request time out at the client side , and I do not get any response from the server , as I expected to success response

Request processing at server is like below:

Start the request

1. Insert details to db table [this process taking time in seconds]
2. Copying files to remote computer server [this process taking 3 minutes]
3. Update/active the files [this process taking time in seconds]
4. Send response to the client

End the request processing

All the above process must be in transaction , so we can not remove any of the above process,

We had already improve the best performance for Step 2 of the process , and it only happens, when we request with the more than 1 gb size file.

As of now for the temporary solution we had increase the timeout value which is configured in the Apache server.

Now I am looking for the solution of my issue, with any of the following  approach:

1. Suggest me any development or implementation strategies which can resolve the my issue and it should be expected as described me?
2. How do I tackle the request time out issue?
3. Looking for the solution which notify the client from the server side , when the  response is done?
4. Looking for the solution which can not close the connection between client and the server with the Jersey REST API implementation?

Thanks & regards 
Yatin Baraiya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as i have think to solve the my issue with the following  approach.

Process implementation step to resolve the my issue

1.At First Sending request to the server ==========> Server immediately send the response to the client with generating some Id and start the long running process by other thread in the same process.

2.At the client side first it receive the first request response and wait for some seconds and then again send other request to the server for the long running process checking status====> Server get the second request and response to the client regarding the the status of the long running  response status with sending  in-progress or done

3.If client get the response :in-progress

4.Then client wait for some seconds and again send the request for status check ===> server Sending response to done

5.If client get the response :Done

1. then it start to take the other request from its queue . [ it will start the process for the next request if and only if client get the done  status and generated ID]

it means here we manage the transaction from the client side  with sending the  multiple request to server and confirm the process is completed successfully or not , then we start to process next action.

With the above approach we got the transaction process ,Let me know is it my approach to solve the said issue , is it enough or any changes is required in this solution?